# React Bootstrap - Duda sobre el sistema de Fila Columna

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap

Estaba trabajando con react bootstrap5 y estaba viendo una galeria dise;ada por otra persona y me surgio la duda si es posible lograr una galeria parecida con el sistema de grid de bootstrap , se como funciona el sistema de de fila y columna de bootstrap pero no tengo tanta experiencia como para saber si es posible acoplar las imagenes como se ven en el ejemplo y queria consultarle a alguien que tenga mas experiencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya gracias

Comment: Sí, [si es posible](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/). Ahora Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu [primera medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/masonry/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregando un poco de codigo css logre este resultado
[image: galeria]

```css
.img-galeria{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.galeria-1-1{
    height: 25%;
}

.galeria-1-2{
    height: 25%;
}

.galeria-2-1{
    height: 35%;
}

.galeria-2-2{
    height: 15%;
}

.galeria-3-1{
    height: 25%;
}

.galeria-3-2{
    height: 25%;
}
```

```html
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col'>
                    <img className='img-galeria galeria-1-1' src={Imagen}></img>
                    <img className='img-galeria galeria-1-2' src={Imagen}></img>
                </div>
                <div className='col-6'>
                    <img className='img-galeria galeria-2-1' src={Imagen}></img>
                    <img className='img-galeria galeria-2-2' src={Imagen}></img>
                </div>
                <div className='col'>
                    <img className='img-galeria galeria-3-1' src={Imagen}></img>
                    <img className='img-galeria galeria-3-2' src={Imagen}></img>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Podes cambiar el valor de height a tu antojo ya sea por % o px.

Las clases indican la columna y fila de la siguiente manera: galeria-(COLUMNA)-(FILA).